# Downloading from bitbucket using REST Api Bitbucket

Tags: curl, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

recently I found that I can use Rest Api Bitbucket to download repositories.
I read the docs, but so far I didn't manage to download any files, but some HTTP headers using `curl`.

Can someone give me a concrete example on how to use the API?

I understand that the command is `curl https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/`, but my bitbucket links is something like this

> http://`company repository site`/projects/`project`/repos/`repo`/

**UPDATE 1**

**

I managed to download a file using curl using the syntax: `curl -u user:pass http://company_repository_site/projects/my_project/repos/my_repo/my_file.ext?raw` but I would still like to know how can this be done using the REST Api

**

Thanks, Daniel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end,  I used

```
curl -u user:pass `bitbucketCompanyServer`/rest/api/1.0/projects/`project`/repos/`repository`/browse/`fullPathToFileOnBitbucket`?at=`commit` > output
```

Hope this helps